# Automatically move email attachments from exchange to sharepoint, and replace with a link

Tags: email, exchange, sharepoint

Our Exchange server is getting rather full, and users are complaining of hitting the limits on their inboxes.

A proposed solution is to scrape all attachments from emails, save them in our Sharepoint system and insert a link to the saved file back into the email.

Is it possible to do this, and is anyone aware of an existing app?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know off-hand of a solution that uses Sharepoint as the back-end, but there are various products like EMC SourceOne and Symantec Enterprise Vault that do it with a database storing the older attachments.

They're not cheap, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Attachment Save for Exchange](http://www.mapilab.com/exchange/attachment_save/) seems like a possibility.  It doesn't look like it plugs directly into SP, but I'd be surprised if SP couldn't absorb files (and hopefully metadata) from a set location.